# cascading drop downs in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get some cascading drop downs in angular that populate based off of what the previous drop down has selected. So basically there are 5 drop downs total, at first only the first drop down would be populated, and then the second one would populate based off of what is picked in the first (hopefully using $http to get the new info back form server base don what is picked) and so on all the way down to 5.

So basically I have this :

```
<select class="selectScope" ng-model="scope1">
                        <option ng-repeat="obj in array" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="selectLevel1" ng-model="scope2">
                        <option ng-repeat="obj in array" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="selectLevel2" ng-model="scope3">
                        <option ng-repeat="obj in array" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="selectLevel3" ng-model="scope4">
                        <option ng-repeat="obj in array" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="selectLevel4" ng-model="scope5">
                        <option ng-repeat="obj in array" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
                    </select>
```

I will have populate the first dropdown with an $http, but without going into detail I am just wondering if I can have the dropdowns trigger off each other. If i have selected all the way down to level 5 and I re-select level 3 - then 4 and 5 would empty (4 would re populate based on what was picked in 3). SO I just want them to work off each other. I am wondering if something like this is possible in angular. Apologies if this is a bit oblivious, I am brand new to using angular. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using `ng-options` instead of an ng-repeat

```
<select ng-model='scope1' ng-change='scope1Change()' 
        ng-options='obj.id as obj.name for obj in array'>
</select>
```

Then, on the ng-change event of the select, you can load the appropriate data for the following selects.

```
$scope.scope1Change = function() {
          //Build URL based on selection
          $http.get(myUrl).then(function(data){
          //transform data if required
           $scope.array2 = data;
    });
}
```

You can keep the other select statements disabled based on previous values being selected

```
<select class="selectLevel1" ng-model="scope2" 
        ng-options='obj.id as obj.name for obj in array2' ng-disabled='!scope1'>
</select>
```

You would need some additional logic in the change events to work out whether or not you should clear the `$scope` model values as required, but that is pretty straightforward

Comment: Ah awesome, angular is so great. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You should be using services as a best practice when doing your $http calls. I've just included them in the controller here for the sake of brevity